# SSIS packages - Available in Database Engine, not in Integrated Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to update one of the .dtsx package, which is visible in Database Engine -> Integration Services Catalogs ->...->Packages. However, once I connect to Integration Services, that package - among others - is not there, therefore not exportable/editable. I am able to see some packages, not all of them though.
SQL job with that package runs fine.

```
select * from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
```

The package is not listed there.
This happened after migration from previous version of MSSQL to MSSQL 2017 as in the previous version of MSSQL all packages were present in Integration Services.
Tried looking for a .dtsx files with no luck.

Any ideas how can I access and edit such .dtsx package?

Comment: Is there more than one instance on the server?

Comment: I believe only one instance on the server:

`Get-ItemProperty ‘HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL’

PRODUCTION   : MSSQL14.PRODUCTION

PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL

PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance  Names

PSChildName  : SQL

PSDrive      : HKLM

PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
`